# LiveData subscriber changed event

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Is it possible for the owner of a LiveData object to listen for new subscribtions/desubscriptions for the LiveData and react on this event?

I have a scenario where the owner will do some background working if there are active listeners - otherwise not.

Comment: You can extend LiveData class and modify it to suit this scenario. The default functionality doesn't support this.

Comment: Maybe try using livedata method `hasActiveObservers()` or just `hasObservers()`

Comment: @UrbanR that won't help, it's not an actual event you can subscribe on, it's just something you can check regularly, at least i imagine that's what OP wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to handle such kind of use-cases is to extend `LiveData` and override [onActive](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#onActive()) and [onInactive](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#onInactive()) methods like it's done [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#extend_livedata). This is more suitable when LiveData itself should perform some actions when becoming active / inactive, but it also should be fairly easy to create a wrapper for a `LiveData` which exposes `isActive` value as a property, something like that should work:

```
class LiveDataWithState<T>(wrapped: LiveData<T>) : MediatorLiveData<T>() {
    private val _isActive = MutableLiveData(false)
    val isActive: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _isActive

    init {
        addSource(wrapped) { value = it }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        _isActive.value = true
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        _isActive.value = false
    }
}
```